# How to properly set up IIS 8 application pool memory limit without triggerring often recycles?

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8.5, application-pools

I am trying to put a limit to the memory used by an application pool within IIS 8.5. My problem is that if I put a limit that looks significantly greater than the typical memory usage, it is recycle once in a few minutes.

Context information comes below.

Initially, I have put a limit of 8GB from the UI and and my applicationhost.config looks like this:

```
<add name="AppPool" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
<processModel idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
<recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
<periodicRestart memory="8192000" time="00:00:00">
<schedule>
<clear />
<add value="01:00:00" />
</schedule>
</periodicRestart>
</recycling>
```

Reading [this article](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart), I realized that the value may be invalid, as it indicates a maximum value of 4,294,967 KB. So, I put this value (from the UI) and it is properly reflected in the configuration file.

If I remove the memory limit, `w3wp` process does not go beyond 2GB of used memory and the recycle does not happen.

The reason of the recycle (reached memory limit) is confirmed by reading Event Viewer (source = WAS).

**Question:** how can I configure the memory limit without the recycle issue?